# webdriverio throws element not visible error after settings its value

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

Trying nodejs and webdriverio first time. This seems to be pretty simple stuff when tried in watir-webdriver or selenium-webdriver gems,but this is confusing me in webdriverio. Why I am getting this error when the driver is already finding the element and setting the value

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'firefox'
}
};
var client=webdriverio.remote(options);

client
.init()
.url('http://www.twitter.com').title(function(err, res) {
console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
})
.isExisting('#signin-password')
.then(function(isExisting){
    console.log(isExisting);
})
.setValue('#signin-password','password')
.then(function(){
    console.log("password set");
})
.isExisting('#signin-email')
.then(function(isExisting){
    console.log("email"+isExisting);
})
.setValue('#signin-email','username')
.then(function(){
    console.log("username set");
});
```

The error I am getting is

```
Title was: Welcome to Twitter - Login or Sign up
true
RuntimeError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'DTNBNAUD10806XS', ip: '10.36.179.144', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at elementIdValue("1", "password") -     at C:\Development\node_modules\webdriverio\lib\commands\setValue.js:52:7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use isExisting you will only get a boolean value in return. To add a little more stability to the test I recommend you use waitForExist or waitForVisible in the case that the DOM is still loading

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the element exists on the web page, but is not visible.

Instead of **isExisting**, use **isVisible**.

Another reason could be that you have more than one element that the selector **`#signin-password`** finds, and the first element that is found is not visible. I'm not saying this is your issue, but this happened to me on some occasions.

You could try to use a more detailed selector like **`#myForm #signin-password`** to make sure you are attempting to set the  value to the correct element.